# Xamarin Forms iOS listview's cell autosize it's content (image from url)

Tags: ios, forms, listview, xamarin, autosize

In Xamarin Forms on iOS side there is a listview. Cells consists of image and text. The images are different sizes and ratio f.e. 300x200 and 300x350. I want to make cell autosize the content so images will fit the whole cell in width, then height of the cell will be autosized depends on image's height.

One way is to calculate row's height depends on image's height - this is working solution, but it is slow when loading images from server. Much faster way is to set ItemsSource to image url and I want to go this way.

I was experimenting with image, ffimageloading, hasUnevenRows, Aspect, put ffimageloading into grid, caching strategy but images are leaving white straps on sides or images are cutted or images are small and after scrolling they are resized to bigger ones.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             xmlns:ffimageloadingsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
             x:Class="Layout.xxx.Views.iOS.CategoryPage"
             x:Name="CategoryPageName">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="CategoryArticles" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" HasUnevenRows="True" CachingStrategy="RetainElement">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame  CornerRadius="5" Margin="5,10,5,10" Padding="0">
                            <Grid Margin="0" Padding="0">
                                <StackLayout Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                        <Grid  Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >
                                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Margin="0"  Source="{Binding PictureUrl}" Aspect="AspectFit" ErrorPlaceholder="default_image.jpg" DownsampleToViewSize="True" />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" />
                                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="5,10,5,10" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" >
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="minus_article.svg" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Quantity}" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="50" Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                            <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage x:Name="AddImage" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="plus.svg" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,10,0"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding PriceLabel}" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,5,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Do you know any other idea? Maybe custom renderer for ffimageloading?

Comment: You can provide the full code in xaml so that  I can test and improve it on my side .

Comment: I have added code. Still working on solution.

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the height of cell in runtime after loading the remote image . You need to call `cell.ForceUpdateSize();` to update the cell's size .

So we use an `TriggerAction` to change this value, and tell the ViewCell to update its size.

```
public class ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeighRequestProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(HeighRequest),
                typeof(double),
                typeof(ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction ),
                60);

    public double HeighRequest{
          get { return (double)GetValue (HeighRequestProperty ); }
          set { SetValue (HeighRequestProperty , value); }
    }

    public ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction() : base()
    {

    }
    protected override void Invoke(VisualElement sender)
    {
        var parent = sender.Parent;
        while (parent != null && !(parent is ViewCell))
        {
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
        if (parent is ViewCell cell)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                sender.HeightRequest = HeighRequest;
                cell.ForceUpdateSize();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Grid.Style>
   <Style TargetType="Grid">
      <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="60"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Grid" Binding="{Binding IsLoadFinished}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <local:ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction HeighRequest="{Binding NewHeight}" />
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <local:ForceUpdateSizeTriggerAction HeighRequest="60" />
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

You can add **IsLoadFinished** and **NewHeight** to your model . And change the value when finish loading the image from url .

Comment: I have added in code behind  to constructor:
ffImage.Success += FfImage_Success;
to xaml's ffimage: x:Name="FfImage"
and then method:

private void FfImage_Success(object sender, FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImageEvents.SuccessEventArgs e)
        {
            var filepath = e.ImageInformation.FilePath;
            var path = e.ImageInformation.Path;
}
so I get filepath directly to image on local storage. How can I calculate image height without using MemoryStream?

Comment: Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32974/how-to-get-an-original-image-size

Comment: Ok, thanks, solution was just under my mouse. One more question. How can I manage with Visual Studio telling me that:
          get { return (double)GetValue (HeighRequestProperty ); }
          set { SetValue (HeighRequestProperty , value); }
    "The name "GetValue" does not exist in current context" and the same for SetValue? What should be inside new implemented methods?

Comment: Delete the `bin` and  `obj` ,then clean and rebuild your project . And `using Xamarin.Forms;`

Comment: I can not deal with "GetValue" does not exist in current context" after doing your instructions many times. At the end I tried to implement those 2 methods - without body ( I know this is not accepted). Then come target invocation excepction, caused by: "System.ArgumentException: 
Default value did not match return type
Parameter name: defaultValue
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty..ctor" then i changed BindableProperty HeighRequestProperty to "60d" instead of "60" but now the application is closing without any stack trace when opening images.

Comment: My answer is just a demo ,you should customize it by yourself .